# Laravel Auth::user() object returns multiple data

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

When I want to display a layout for admins, it should only use one layout but it also uses the member layout, and vice versa.

Here is the code:

```
@if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin')

    @extends('layouts/admin')

@elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'member')

    @extends('layouts/member')

@endif

@section('content')

    <h1>Hello world</h1>

@endsection
```

When I sign-in an admin account, it displays both navbars for admin and member. I only need one.

Comment: Check blade files. (admin and member)  Maybe there is something wrong with them.

Comment: Does your admin and member layout contains navbar or there are separate files for navbar ?

Comment: my admin and member have different navbars

Comment: if else statement just get one part. Can't get admin and member. Problem is probably in your blades.

Comment: could you take a look on the compiled views? it should be in `storage/framework/views`.. if that one code did not reflect the correct blade, throw an `php artisan view:clear` to purge the compiled view caches.

Comment: @aronccs Check your blade files then carefully, maybe something wrong with them.

Comment: I have figured it out, turns out i should have used `@include` instead of `@extends`

Comment: First of all, test your code by :if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin')

   dd('admin');

elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'member')

    dd('member');
endif      Put @ before each conditional statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change extends lines:

```
@extends('layouts/admin')
```

for include:

```
@include('layouts/admin')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change `@extends` to `@include` and its all good.

```
@if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin')

@include('layouts/admin')

@elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'member')

@include('layouts/member')

@endif

@section('content')

<h1>Hello world</h1>

@endsection
```